# Sonar forces me to choose between FindBugs results or JaCoCo integration test coverage

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I have this strange problem in Sonar. I am using Sonar 3.2 + Ant + JaCoCo + Selenium.

I setup my sonar.binaries properties file in the Ant target, which is executed through Jenkins.

1) If I set the sonar.binaries property to point to my generated .class files, then FindBugs works fine but my JaCoCo Integration Test coverage displays 0%. The 0% is probably due to the fact that the class files are not the exact ones being deployed to the JBoss server, therefore Sonar cannot do the mapping.

2) If I set the sonar.binaries property to point to my .jar files (i.e. includes the above .class files) then FindBugs will give an exception upon build. After disabling FindBugs the Sonar build finishes fine, and this time I get the correct JaCoCo IT code coverage for all of my binaries!

Any thoughts? :)

Comment: interestingly, it is like comma separated values does not work for the sonar.binaries property? I have added three folders to the property, but only the first one is chosen. So I get IT code coverage only for the folder of class files that I have first specified :) the other folders separated with a comma are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are experiencing the bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-164 - "The Sonar JaCoCo plugin takes into account only the first binary directories if several ones are provided"

This is due to be fixed in the next release of the Sonar Java Ecosystem plugin (1.3), which however is not released yet.

Comment: thanks Simon for the verification. Yes it seems like I am experiencing this bug. I got around it somehow (can't remember exactly) by importing all .class files (including .jar files) and then excluding some files. I imported folders, not individual class or jar files.